# Capturing the resolved SASS parent selector

Tags: sass

I'm trying to find a way to capture the resolved parent selector (`&`) in SASS (*running 3.2.3*), likely in a mixin.

Unfortunately (*and I've found discussion of this on github*) the following go-to solution doesn't work:

```
@mixin append-to-captured-parent($append) {
    $selector: "&-#{$append}";
    #{$selector} { @content; }
}

.foo {
    @include append-to-captured-parent("bar") {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

The desired output being:

```
.foo .foo-bar { color: blue; }
```

Are there any hacks or work-arounds that can result in the desired output? As I understand it, this is likely not possible, as the parent selector isn't resolved until the SASS parser has constructed the entire node tree, at which point it encounters `&-bar { ... }`, on which it dies:

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "&": expected "{", was "-bar"
```

Can we trick SASS into resolving this pre-emptively?

**Note:** I'm more than open to SASS extensions (*Ruby libs*) that can accomplish this; unfortunately at this time I'm not Ruby-savvy enough to roll my own (*I'm working on it though*)

Comment: @CourtS Nah; this was a shot in the dark. As I mentioned, it appears the parser performs the parent selector substitution after it's bricked on invalid syntax.

Comment: @CourtS Well, I've answered my question with a work-around; have a look-see if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've come up with a work-around, sort of.

This approach merely isolates the intended functionality, and manages it independently of the actual hierarchy.

First, some quick utilities:

```
@function slice($list, $from, $into) {
    $result: ();
    @for $index from $from through $into {
        $result: append($result, nth($list, $index));
    }
    @return $result;
}

@function implode($list, $separator) {
    $result: nth($list, 1);
    @for $index from 2 through length($list) {
        $result: #{$result}#{$separator}#{nth($list, $index)};
    }
    @return $result;
}
```

Then the guts:

```
$-class: ();
@function get-class() {
    $top: if(length($-class) - 2 < 1, 1, length($-class) - 2);
    @return implode(slice($-class, $top, length($-class)), "-");
}

@mixin class($name) {
    $-class: append($-class, $name);
    .#{get-class()} {
        @content;
    }
    $-class: slice($-class, 1, length($-class) - 1);
}
```

What happens here is, the "global" variable `$-class`, maintains a nesting stack with each invocation of the mixin `class`. It creates a CSS class declaration by imploding the top three names on the stack (*this can be modified to the full stack if desired*)

So replicating the question's example:

```
@include class (foo) {
    color: red;
    @include class (bar) {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Will produce:

```
.foo { color: red; }
.foo .foo-bar { color: blue; }
```

A less trivial example would be:

```
@include class(list) {
    test: "list";
    @include class(item) {
        test: "item";
        @include class(heading) {
            test: "heading";
        }
        @include class(content) {
            test: "content";
            @include class(graphic) {
                test: "graphic";
            }
            @include class(summary) {
                test: "summary";
            }
            @include class(details) {
                test: "details";
            }
        }
        @include class(footing) {
            test: "footing";
        }
    }
}
```

Producing:

```
.list { test: "list"; }
.list .list-item { test: "item"; }
.list .list-item .list-item-heading { test: "heading"; }
.list .list-item .list-item-content { test: "content"; }
.list .list-item .list-item-content .item-content-graphic { test: "graphic"; }
.list .list-item .list-item-content .item-content-summary { test: "summary"; }
.list .list-item .list-item-content .item-content-details { test: "details"; }
.list .list-item .list-item-footing { test: "footing"; }
```